# CommandArgument is not working with Eval in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In my aspx page I have bound a value from a list into command argument  of a link button. After clicking the button I cant get any value.

Code of aspx page :

```
<% foreach (common.service.Model.CourseSection item in sectionList)
 { %>
       <tr>                                            
           <td>  <%= item.ScheduleId%>  </td>
           <td>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("item.InstructorFullName") %>'  runat="server" OnCommand="btnAddSyllabus_Click">Add</asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
       </tr>
 <%} %>
```

In the cs page into the myVal variable I found just empty string.

```
protected void btnAddSyllabus_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{

    string myVal = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are using `LinkButton` inside `GridView` or `Repeater` like control then it should work. Otherwise remove `Eval` and just use

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" CommandArgument='<%# item.InstructorFullName %>'  runat="server" OnCommand="btnAddSyllabus_Click">Add</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: I am using LinkButton inside a simple html table. And if I put your code into my code it show error "The name 'Item' does not exists in the current context."

Comment: Try replacing # by =

Comment: Tried that.  It pass string "<%= item.InstructorFullName %>" as command argument.